# Downloading Zipped Collection of files via C# MVC - non-blocking download

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, zip

I have an C#, API, using .NET-CORE and I am looking for an option to do a download of a zipped file with contents that are coming from a SharePoint REST client.

The idea should be:

- user clicks "download"
- server determines files to be included
- download starts
- server downloads the files from SharePoint (one-by-one) - in background
- add them to the zip file
- return the zip file as a Stream/File

Downsides of the current method is that the generation of the file can take a long time and therefore the call return is blocked until such time that all files have been included.

I am pretty sure there must be a way to add files to a download stream instead if having to create the whole thing in memory first?
But I can't seem to find information on the topic?

The idea would be that the user clicks the download and the "download" starts whilst in the background the server is collecting the files from SharePoint and feeding them to the user return stream?

Anybody have any good suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone coming across a similar challenge.
I have been able to resolve this by implementing HangFire on the backend
see: [HangFire](https://www.hangfire.io/)

Implemented as a 2 step process:

1. Trigger fire-and-forget action on Hangfire which downloads the files and combines them into a .zip file which gets saved as a downloadable file on the API-server.
2. Send an email to the requesting user that the file was succesfully created with a link to the relevant file

The latter also allows other people to see which files have already been created and what their 'age' is. They can then choose to download either the existing file or trigger a 'refresh'